# Find first subkey that has specific value

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am struggling to finish up this batch file and I am not sure what I am missing, although I am certain it's a small mistake. I think it's with my delims or possibly the subkey naming convention.

```
@echo off
@echo 12 (2014)
@echo 13 (2016)
@echo 14 (2017)
@echo 15 (2019)

set /p "version=Enter Version: "
set "value_name=ParentInstance"
set "value_data=MSSQL%version%E.LOCALDB"
set "key_path=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances"

for /f "tokens=2* delims={}" %%a in ('reg query "%key_path%" /s 2^>nul') do (
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('reg query "%%b" /v "%value_name%" 2^>nul') do (
        set "subkey=%%b"
        goto :break
    )
)
:break
if defined subkey (
    reg add "%subkey%" /v "%value_name%" /t REG_SZ /d "%value_data%" /f
    echo Updated Value data of key : %subkey% to : %value_data%
) else (
    echo Subkey with value name "%value_name%" not found.
)
endlocal
TIMEOUT /t 5 /nobreak
```

I am looking for a way to retrieve all subkeys under

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
> Server\UserInstances

Then for each subkey check if it has a value named **"ParentInstance"** by querying the value under that subkey. If it finds any, it stores that subkey in the variable **"subkey"**, then uses the reg add command to change the data of the value named **"ParentInstance"** to the value in the variable **"value_data"** which is **"MSSQL%version%E.LOCALDB"** (%version% is a number that gets input).

Example of Registry (UserInstances may include multiple subkeys)

[image]

Comment: Immediately obvious: You have two nested `for/f` statements, the first sets `%%a` and `%%b`, the second `%%b` and `%%c`. How is `cmd` supposed to figure out which `%%b` you mean - the inner or the outer loop? Change the metavariable in one or the other with the obvious consequential changes. Next - be careful about `%` in values. They may need to be doubled to achieve what you want.

Comment: Okay, I do notice that now. I changed the nested for loop to `for /f "tokens=2*" %%b in ('reg query "%key_path%\%%a" /v "%value_name%" 2^>nul') do (` however I am still getting empty results when it should be finding the value ParentInstance in the path. I am not sure where you are getting %%c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform the task using the same methodology you laid out in your question:

- Get all next level subkeys within your `%key_path%`, *(I added some additional robustness targeting only those child keys with the format `{*-*-*-*-*}`)*.
- For each of those subkeys, query if it has a value named `%value_name%`.
- If it finds any, change the value data for `%value_name%` for that subkey using the `reg add` command to the content of the variable, `%value_data%`.

```bash
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%key_path%" /F "{*-*-*-*-*}" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "\"') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%%G" /F "%value_name%" /V /E 2>NUL 1>&2 && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "%%G" /V "%value_name%" /D "%value_data%" /F 1>NUL
```

Comment: With this I can essentially replace everything under my last variable? And it loops through every case rather than just the first one found? Very insightful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
set "key_path=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances"

for /f "tokens=2* delims={}" %%a in ('reg query "%key_path%" /s 2^>nul') do (
echo %%%% a=%%a %%%% b=%%b
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%B in ('reg query "%%b" /v "%value_name%" 2^>nul') do (
echo %%%% B=%%B %%%% C=%%C
        set "subkey=%%b"
        goto :break
    )
)
```

Note that the metavariables `a`, `b`, `B` and `C` is one of the few instances in batch where case is significant. `%%b` and `%%B` are different variable.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.

`for /f "tokens=2,*delims={}" %%u...` will parse the text line in question, assign the second "token"  to `%%u` and the rest-of-the-line-after-token-2 (`*`) to `%%v`.

Tokens are calculated left-to-right from the format `{delimiters}token1{delimiters}token2{delimiters}token3{delimiters}token4...` - leading delimiters optional, and `{delimiters}` is any string of any delimiter specified between `delims=` and `"`.

Comment: I see now. I was misunderstanding tokens. I concatenated `%key_path%\{%%a}` in the second for loop and also adjusted that loop to `for /f "tokens=*"` in order to get the full path of the subkey where the `%value_name%` is found. Passing `subkey` to equal `%%b` then updating the data for the specified subkey path. Thank You!